# Typing and seeing math equations on WordPress site

Tags: customization

Can a WordPress site display math equations as you type in input field so that you can check what you are typing?

Comment: Not sure which input field you are talking about and where do you wan to display it? FYI WordPress provides us WYSIWYG (What You See is What You Get) editor as described in this page https://en.support.wordpress.com/visual-editor/

Comment: just like in this SE site when you type an answer in the input field in Tex code you can see what you are typing... like the preview of your Tex code in actual math equations as they will apeear

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post you can read about LaTeX (it's on the main WordPress support site): https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/.

Here's a plugin you could have a look at also: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-latex/

Comment: @user12345: Honestly, I couldn't tell you - I've never used it. I was trying to find some screenshots of the plugin in use, but by the sounds of things, it does not have a live editor - unfortunately.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click the tick to make it the accepted/best answer so everyone else can see it. Glad I helped you :)